# NextJS: How to add screen loading for production build?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want add screen loading in next js project. And I tried to do that with the Router component in `next/router`.

This is my _app.js in next.js project:

```js
import {CookiesProvider} from 'react-cookie';
import App from 'next/app'
import React from 'react'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import withRedux from 'next-redux-wrapper'
import withReduxSaga from 'next-redux-saga'
import createStore from '../src/redux/store'
import Router from "next/router";
import {Loaded, Loading} from "../src/util/Utils";

class MyApp extends App {

    static async getInitialProps({Component, ctx}) {
        let pageProps = {};

        if (Component.getInitialProps) {
            pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps({ctx})
        }

        return {pageProps}
    }

    render() {
        Router.onRouteChangeStart = () => {
            Loading()
        };

        Router.onRouteChangeComplete = () => {
            Loaded()
        };

        Router.onRouteChangeError = () => {
            Loaded()
        };

        const {Component, pageProps, store} = this.props;
        return (
            <CookiesProvider>
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                </Provider>
            </CookiesProvider>
        )
    }
}

export default withRedux(createStore)(withReduxSaga(MyApp))
```

This is `Loaded()` and `Loading()` functions:

```js
export const Loaded = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        let loading = 'has-loading';
        document.body.classList.remove(loading);
    }, 100);
};

export const Loading = () => {
    let loading = 'has-loading';
    document.body.classList.add(loading);
};
```

The code works well when the project is under development mode. But when the project is built, the loading won't disappear.

Do you know solution of this issue or are you suggesting another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following codes to a wrapper component and the problem was resolved.

```js
componentDidMount() {
    Loaded();
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    Loading();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `apollo client` and `react hooks` you could do as follow.

Example:

```
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

import { withApollo } from '../lib/apollo';
import UserCard from '../components/UserCard';

export const USER_INFO_QUERY = gql`
  query getUser ($login: String!) {
    user(login: $login) {
      name
      bio
      avatarUrl
      url
    }
  }
`;

const Index = () => {
  const { query } = useRouter();
  const { login = 'default' } = query;
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(USER_INFO_QUERY, {
    variables: { login },
  });

  if (loading) return 'Loading...';            // Loading component
  if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`; // Error component

  const { user } = data;

  return (
    <UserCard
      float
      href={user.url}
      headerImg="example.jpg"
      avatarImg={user.avatarUrl}
      name={user.name}
      bio={user.bio}
    />
  );
};

export default withApollo({ ssr: true })(Index);
```

More info here: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-apollo